# Storing Variables in UWP C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've been writing Universal Windows Apps for over a month now, and I wanted to make sure that I was storing variables I want to use throughout the entire app in the appropriate place. What I have been doing is placing variables in App.xaml.cs and creating an App variable that references the current app as follows

```
private App obj = (App)App.Current;
```

I am then able to grab the variables that I sotre in App.xaml.cs and use it when needed. Is this a correct way of storing information or is there a better way of storing these variables?

Comment: Storing as in saving, on "disk" or storage? If it's just memory: your method is a bit rough but valid. An alternative would be to use a static object. If you tend to save data to storage: this is insufficient.

Comment: Oh, so just make all the variables static?

Comment: the most appropriate way is to use service that is shared throughout your application and get the instance using dependency injection and IOC containers but if you are a beginner then you should go the route you go at the moment.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Per your description, I think what you need is [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx), take a look at [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx).

Code will be like the following

Create a setting

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = 
    new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
composite["intVal"] = 1;
composite["strVal"] = "string";

localSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"] = composite;
```

Retrieve a setting

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = 
   (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"];

if (composite == null)
{
   // No data
}
else
{
   // Access data in composite["intVal"] and composite["strVal"]
}
```